# After removing alert view from didReceiveLocalNotification in active state,no notification is coming in foreground

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications

I'm implementing local notifications,there are 3 notifications to be send at different times of a day.
in my app delegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.


    if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];
    }
}
```

and in DidReceiveLocalNotifications

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{

NSString *checkbtn= [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"on"];

    if([checkbtn isEqualToString:@"SwitchOn"])
    {
    UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
    if (state == UIApplicationStateActive) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Green Actions"
                                                        message:notification.alertBody
                                                       delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }


    }

    // Set icon badge number to zero
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
//}

}
```

if i remove this alert view,i m not getting any notification in foreground but if i use this then i m getting notification alert every second.

this is my viewcontroller code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    appdelegate= (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    [self createCustomeNavigationBar];


    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
    //[self notificationOne];


    [self.switchbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(switchToggled:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.switchbutton1 addTarget:self action:@selector(switchToggled1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.switchbutton3 addTarget:self action:@selector(switchToggled3:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

     if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"on"])
     {

    UILocalNotification* n1 = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    n1.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: 160];
    n1.alertBody = @"one";
         [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification: n1];
     }
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"SwitchOneon"])
    {
    UILocalNotification* n2 = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    n2.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: 190];
    n2.alertBody = @"two";
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification: n2];
    }


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
- (void) switchToggled:(id)sender {
    self.switchbutton = (UISwitch *)sender;
    if ([self.switchbutton   isOn]) {
        NSLog(@"its on!");

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:@"SwitchOn" forKey:@"on"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];



    } else {

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]removeObjectForKey:@"on"];

        NSLog(@"its off!");

    }
}


- (void) switchToggled1:(id)sender {
    self.switchbutton1 = (UISwitch *)sender;
    if ([self.switchbutton1   isOn]) {
        NSLog(@"its on!");

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:@"SwitchOn" forKey:@"SwitchOneon"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];



    } else {

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]removeObjectForKey:@"SwitchOneon"];

        NSLog(@"its off!");

    }
}

- (void) switchToggled3:(id)sender {
    self.switchbutton3 = (UISwitch *)sender;
    if ([self.switchbutton3   isOn]) {
        NSLog(@"its on!");

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:@"SwitchOn" forKey:@"SwitchThreeon"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];



    } else {

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]removeObjectForKey:@"SwitchThreeon"];

        NSLog(@"its off!");

    }
}
```

and also i m getting some different text in alert view which i used earlier just for testing purpose,even after changing it,i m getting the same old previous text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure that problem isn't with alert code. `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification`, you're getting notification. But when your app is in foreground (or active) you should handle it manually. In your case, you're handling it with `UIAlertView` so it will be visible in alert, but once you removed, you're not able to see a notification when your app was in foreground (or active) state.

Comment: then how can i handle local notifications if app is foreground

Comment: Explain your requirement so I can help you better.

Comment: i have 3 toggle buttons,if they are turned on,i have to show notifications,there r 3 different notifications to be send

Comment: That's your app requirement, but I'm asking about your first comment. What you're doing when getting a notification? What you want to do?